# Push Html Form data to JSON file using Angular 2

Tags: angular, json.net, angular2-forms

Am getting the data from JSON file locally. now i wan to send the HTML form data to JSON file.
I have tried:my component.ts file code:

```
onSelectionChange(entry: any) {
  debugger;
  this.radiovalue = entry;
  console.log(this.radiovalue);


  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  //options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  //options = headers;

  let body = JSON.stringify(this.radiovalue);
  return this._http.post(this._url, body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());

}

[
  {
    "Qno": 1,
    "QuestionText": "Which of the following object is ideal for keeping data alive for a single request?",
    "QuestionType": "radio",
    "AnswerOptions": [
      {
        "name": "HttpContext",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Session",
        "value": 2
      }],
    "UserAnswers": []
  },

  {
    "Qno": 2,
    "QuestionText": "Which of the following does NOT require type casting?",
    "QuestionType": "dropdown",
    "AnswerOptions": [
      {
        "name": "Session",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "ViewBag",
        "value": 2
      }
    ],
    "UserAnswers": []

  }
```

I want to send the form data to `UserAnswers[]`, I tried but getting an error.

```
UserAnswers[name:value:]
```

any suggestion on this.

Comment: please format your  question. What is the error you are getting ? What is the value of entry when you try your code ?

Comment: need to update the json data based upon the user selection from the html component.so i have to write ti the UserAnswers[].